# C Pointers/HTTP parser (why won't my code work)

Tags: c, pointers

I thought I knew some basics about C pointers but I cannot figure out what is wrong with this very basic start to a HTTP GET request parser.

I've stepped through the code and verified that strstr() is returning the correct string.  But, the line 'p_server = pSubString'  is not working. It is trying to write where p_server points which causes a SIG fault.  I've tried a bunch of different variations with & and * operators but without luck.

Also, the book I'm working from (UNIX SYSTEMS Programming by Kay and Steven Robbins 19.8 p.676) said the parse function should take pointers-to-pointers (i.e., **p_path).  Any ideas why?  (After trying p2p I went to regular pointers because I thought it would be easier).

```
int parse(char *inlin, char *p_command, char *p_server, char *p_path, char *p_protocol, char *p_port)
{

int length;
char * pSubString;

p_command  = inlin;
pSubString   = my_strstr( inlin, "www");   
p_server = pSubString;

pSubString   = my_strstr( p_server, "/");
p_path = pSubString;

pSubString   = my_strstr( p_path, "HTTP");
p_protocol = pSubString;
}
```

Thanks!

PS: the `my_strstr()` is the library `strstr()`.  I just put a copy in my code so I could step through it with GDB.

Comment: You are almost certainly misdiagnosing the problem. `p_server = pSubString` cannot be causing a seg fault as it is not dereferencing any pointer. If you want help please provide a [minimal complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and stating exactly what the behaviour of the program is.

Comment: Try running your code through [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) as well and see if that finds any memory leaks.

Comment: Get your C book back in hand and read more about pointers-to-pointers, and how strings are stored in memory; even after the SIGSEGV is "fixed", your code does not look correct at all to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you do need "pointer to pointer"... This code for example:

```
pSubString   = my_strstr( inlin, "www");   
p_server = pSubString;
```

sets "p_server" to the address of where "www" was found.  Which does NOT change the pointer that was used in the "call" to "parse()"... so it would be lost as soon as `parse()` returns.

Assume you modify `parse()` as follows:

```
int parse(char *inlin, char **p_command, char **p_server, char **p_path, char **p_protocol, char **p_port)
{

    int length;
    char * pSubString;

    p_command  = inlin;
    pSubString   = my_strstr( inlin, "www");   
    *p_server = pSubString;

    pSubString   = my_strstr( p_server, "/");
    *p_path = pSubString;

    pSubString   = my_strstr( p_path, "HTTP");
    *p_protocol = pSubString;
}
```

Assume you call `parse()` from the following snippet:

```
char *my_command  = NULL;
char *my_server   = NULL;
char *my_path     = NULL;
char *my_protocol = NULL;
char *my_port     = NULL;
parse(buffer, &my_command, &my_server, &my_path, &my_protocol, &my_port);
```

After this change, the value of the "my_" variables, will contain the addresses from the various calls to my_strstr()in parse().

Comment: Thanks so much TonyB.  Your explanation really helped me get it working.